Jasypt не шифрует конфигурационный файл
Проблема в том, что jasypt не шифрует строки помеченные DEC() в application.yml файле.
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
 <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
 <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>

<plugin>
 <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
 <artifactId>jasypt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>3.0.3</version>
</plugin>

server:
  port: 80888

password: DEC(12345)
password1: DEC(123456)
password2: DEC(123457)
password3: DEC(1234567)

@Configuration
public class JasyptEncryptorConfig {

    @Bean(name = "jasyptStringEncryptor")
    public StringEncryptor passwordEncryptor(){
        PooledPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new PooledPBEStringEncryptor();
        SimpleStringPBEConfig config = new SimpleStringPBEConfig();
        config.setPassword("javatechie"); // encryptor's private key
        config.setAlgorithm("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        config.setKeyObtentionIterations("1000");
        config.setPoolSize("1");
        config.setProviderName("SunJCE");
        config.setSaltGeneratorClassName("org.jasypt.salt.RandomSaltGenerator");
        config.setStringOutputType("base64");
        encryptor.setConfig(config);
        return  encryptor;
    }

}

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEncryptableProperties
public class JasyptToolApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JasyptToolApplication.class, args);
    }

}

Запускаю приложение, но ничего не происходит. Значения остаются ровно такими же.
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.3.5)

2024-11-01T12:54:28.463+03:00  INFO 8552 --- [JasyptTool] [           main] r.cmx.jasypttool.JasyptToolApplication   : Starting JasyptToolApplication using Java 17.0.2 with PID 8552 (C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\JasyptTool\target\classes started by User in C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\JasyptTool)
2024-11-01T12:54:28.465+03:00  INFO 8552 --- [JasyptTool] [           main] r.cmx.jasypttool.JasyptToolApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-11-01T12:54:28.802+03:00  INFO 8552 --- [JasyptTool] [           main] ptablePropertiesBeanFactoryPostProcessor : Post-processing PropertySource instances
2024-11-01T12:54:28.802+03:00  INFO 8552 --- [JasyptTool] [           main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Skipping PropertySource configurationProperties [class org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertySource
2024-11-01T12:54:28.804+03:00  INFO 8552 --- [JasyptTool] [           main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource systemProperties [org.springframework.core.env.PropertiesPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2024-11-01T12:54:28.804+03:00  INFO 8552 --- [JasyptTool] [           main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource systemEnvironment [org.springframework.boot.env.SystemEnvironmentPropertySourceEnvironmentPostProcessor$OriginAwareSystemEnvironmentPropertySource] to EncryptableSystemEnvironmentPropertySourceWrapper
2024-11-01T12:54:28.804+03:00  INFO 8552 --- [JasyptTool] [           main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource random [org.springframework.boot.env.RandomValuePropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper
2024-11-01T12:54:28.804+03:00  INFO 8552 --- [JasyptTool] [           main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource Config resource 'class path resource [application.properties]' via location 'optional:classpath:/' [org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedMapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2024-11-01T12:54:28.804+03:00  INFO 8552 --- [JasyptTool] [           main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource Config resource 'class path resource [application.yml]' via location 'optional:classpath:/' [org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedMapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2024-11-01T12:54:28.804+03:00  INFO 8552 --- [JasyptTool] [           main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource password [org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2024-11-01T12:54:28.869+03:00  INFO 8552 --- [JasyptTool] [           main] c.u.j.filter.DefaultLazyPropertyFilter   : Property Filter custom Bean not found with name 'encryptablePropertyFilter'. Initializing Default Property Filter
2024-11-01T12:54:28.875+03:00  INFO 8552 --- [JasyptTool] [           main] c.u.j.r.DefaultLazyPropertyResolver      : Property Resolver custom Bean not found with name 'encryptablePropertyResolver'. Initializing Default Property Resolver
2024-11-01T12:54:28.877+03:00  INFO 8552 --- [JasyptTool] [           main] c.u.j.d.DefaultLazyPropertyDetector      : Property Detector custom Bean not found with name 'encryptablePropertyDetector'. Initializing Default Property Detector
2024-11-01T12:54:28.951+03:00  INFO 8552 --- [JasyptTool] [           main] r.cmx.jasypttool.JasyptToolApplication   : Started JasyptToolApplication in 0.801 seconds (process running for 1.193)

mvn команда отрабатывает и все шифрует. хочется добиться такого же результата при запуске приложения.
